# Sub Total - Calculated with discount

Tags: checkout

Were having an issue with our subtotal.

In our case a discount has been applied.  Magento Should be providing a **10%** discount on the **89.99** sale Which should equate to **9.99**

Its actualy providing a **10.80** discount
The subtotal is also reflecting this value at **79.19**

But the grand total is showing the correct value at **£80.99**

Any clues on how to continue debugging this ?

*note* : This is based on a discount code

Comment: Please reformat the question.
"Magento is Should be providing a 10% discount In this case on 89.99 Wich should equate to 9.99" is not clear.

Comment: "In our case a discount has been applied. Magento Should be providing a 10% discount on the 89.99 sale Which should equate to 9.99

Comment: What is your tax settings?  Any external modules?

Comment: tax settings https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgjeyia19riev0d/Screenshot%202014-08-27%2010.38.31.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actualy fixed this in a rather cool way.  Firstly I removed all of the junk other developers placed in the site!  Sub 400 Lines of Jquery.... Just to try and do this.

```
//Gets the Data From Magento
$datalot = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData();
//This Array is huge,  Lots of values.  Print it out to see!
//Our client wanted the subtotal to equil Grand total - Base shipping
$realsub = $datalot['grand_total'] - $datalot['base_shipping_incl_tax'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look to debug around:

```
 Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator::process()

and Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator::processShippingAmount()
```

Also if might help to check what is happening at item level.